# How to compare lines from a text file in Python?

Tags: python, file

hope this is not a trivial question since I'm new to Python.
I have a text file, and I need to compare the first line with all the following ones, than the second line with all the following ones, etc. 
If it was a list I'd just make two for loops, but I don't know how to start reading a file from the line after the one that needs to be compared.
Could someone help me?

Comment: you could use `open('input.txt').readlines()`, it will return the file lines as a list.
if that doesn't help, please provide a sample of the data file you need to loop through and the expected output.

Comment: Your problem is how to read lines from a text file in Python...so you should have a title about that :P But be sure to do some searching it first before you ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list with each line as an element using a [readlines()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readlines.htm) function.

```
with open(file_name) as file:
    lines_list = f.readlines()
```

Comment: Thank you man! I've tried this solution, it's a little intricate in some points (cause every line of the file is a series of numbers that I have to put in another list) but it seems to work

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a list of all the lines:

```
with open(path_to_file) as f:
    list_of_lines = f.readlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in f1:
    for line_aux in f2:
        compare the two lines
```

Comment: But in this case you'll compare the first line of f1 with the first line of f2

Comment: this compares the first line of f1 with every line of f2, then the second line of f1 with every line of f2, and so on and so on

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that f1 and f2 are the same file and I don't want to compare the first line with the first line.

Comment: Oh ok, i missunderstood the question then, your best bet then is to use one of the other answers, using f.readlines() to get a list of files and then use that list to make the for loops like you said